# Latex bibliography Elsevier

Tags: bibtex

I have a problem with my bibliography in LaTeX. I use a template from Elsevier with the style: `\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}`.

Here´s the result.

> Rahul , Sandeep G, Chakraborty D, Dutta A. Multi-objective optimization of hybrid laminates subjected to transverse impact. Composite Structures 2006;73(3):360-9.

There’s a space between the comma after the first author when running the following:

```
@article{Rahul|Chakraborty20052003,
title = "Optimization of {FRP} composites against impact induced failure using island model parallel genetic algorithm",
journal = "Composites Science and Technology ",
volume = "65",
number = "13",
pages = "2003 - 2013",
year = "2005",
note = "",
issn = "0266-3538",
author = "Rahul and D. Chakraborty and A. Dutta",
keywords = "Hybrid composite laminate",
keywords = "Optimization",
keywords = "Island model parallel genetic algorithm",
keywords = "Finite element method",
keywords = "Contact impact "
}
```

Note that the first author´s name is just Rahul. The results are indifferent when I tried the following alternatives at the "author" line:

```
author = "{Rahul} and D. Chakraborty and A. Dutta",
author = {{Rahul} and D. Chakraborty and A. Dutta},
author = "{} Rahul and D. Chakraborty and A. Dutta",
author = "{}Rahul and D. Chakraborty and A. Dutta",
author = "Rahul{} and D. Chakraborty and A. Dutta",
```

Comment: I would suggest to stop worrying about the minor niceties of bibliography formatting, particularly with Elsevier. My reason is that Elsevier, like other major publishers, will process your bibliography in order to match the cited items with their databases and then reformat them to insert hyperlinks etc. I have not had any complaints about bibliography formatting from any publisher in the last 5 years or so, even though I didn't spend much time on polishing the bibliographies.

Answer (score 3):

A very ugly hack:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Rahul|Chakraborty20052003,
  author = "Rahul, {\relax} and Chakraborty, D. and Dutta, A.",
  title = "Optimization of {FRP} composites against impact induced failure using island model parallel genetic algorithm",
  journal = "Composites Science and Technology ",
  volume = "65",
  number = "13",
  pages = "2003-2013",
  year = "2005",
  note = "",
  issn = "0266-3538",
  keywords = "Hybrid composite laminate",
  keywords = "Optimization",
  keywords = "Island model parallel genetic algorithm",
  keywords = "Finite element method",
  keywords = "Contact impact",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{elsarticle}

\makeatletter
\def\xfnm[#1]{%
  \def\xfnmarg{#1}\def\xfnmrelax{ {\relax}.}%
  \ifx\xfnmarg\xfnmrelax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {,\@gobble}%
  {\unskip,\space#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{Rahul|Chakraborty20052003}

\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The bibliography style uses `\xfnm` for typesetting the initials; I redefine it so, in case the first name is `{\relax}`, the entry is basically ignored and just produces a comma.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for spending your coming up with the solution. The space between the first authour Rahul and the following comma is revmoved. We, however, have problems with the name of the rest of the authors as well as a double dots behind behind the last author.

Comment: @livyiitc That's wanted. You get it for every list of authors.